# What is the derivative of $f(x)$ if $f(x)+f(y)=f\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$?

Tags: derivatives, functional-equations

> **Question.** What is the derivative of $f(x)$ if $f(x)+f(y)=f\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$?

So my solution is the following:

Differentiating with respect to $x$ gives

$$ f'(x) = f '\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right) $$

Let $x=0$ then $f'(0)=f '(y)$ for all $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$. So the derivative is constant.

So my problem is that I can't solve this but also I don't know what I've done wrong. This seems perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! Please try to use MathJaX to typeset equations (here is a [useful guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)). As for your question, the derivative on the right-hand side is wrong, it is a derivative of the form $(u\circ v)'$

Comment: As pointed out by the comment above, you need the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) to correctly compute the derivative of the right-hand side.

Comment: Do they tell you that $f$ is differentiable? That functional equation has solutions that are not differentiable. Define $g(x)=f(\tan(x))$. Then we get that $g(x)+g(y)=g(x+y)$, which is [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). So, the solutions of your functional equation are the solutions of Cauchy's equation composed with $\arctan$. If they tell you that $f$ is differentiable somewhere, then the solutions are $f(x)=c\arctan(x)$ and then $f'(x)=\frac{c}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: Did you miss $f$ in the RHS?

Comment: f is differntiable, more specifically the derivative function is continuous. $f'(x)=\left(\frac{c}{x^2+1}\right)$ is the right anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have almost solved it.

$f'(x)=f'\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)\left(\frac{(1-xy)-(x+y)(-y)}{(1-xy)^2}\right)$

Let $x=0$, then
$f'(0)=f'(y)(1+y^2)$, thus $f'(y)=\frac{c}{1+y^2}$ for all $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

So we have $f(y)=c*\arctan y+C$ where $C=0$ since $f(0)=0$.

I know the function that I've gotten satisfies the functional equation if $xy<1$.

So if I want to show that the functional equation is satisfied, must I prove that $\arctan x+\arctan y=\arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$ for $xy<1$ or is it enough that I got $f(y)$ based on $x=0$ and $y$ is any real number so $xy<1$?

Comment: Just like the argument up to $f(y)=c\arctan(y)+C$ included some spurious solutions $C\neq0$ that had to be removed, potentially in the family $f(y)=c\arctan(y)$ there are still some that don't satisfy the functional equation. So, yes in your line of argument one still would need to verify that all of these satisfy the original functional equation.

Comment: The identity $\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)=\arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$ can be deduced from the identity $\tan(a+b)=\frac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)}$, which probably you know. You only need to replace $a=\arctan(x)$, $b=\arctan(y)$ and apply $\arctan$ on both sides.